# I have all 12 phrase words, but can't figure out the order of the last six words. What do I do?

Tags: wallet-recovery, mnemonic-seed, trust-wallet

I'm trying to recover my Trust Wallet account. I have all 12 words of my phrase. For 6 of them I strongly believe that I know the right order but the remaining 6 words are completely random. Is there a way I can figure out the order of the remaining 6 words?

Comment: Was there a particular reason why you added the tag [trust-wallet]?

Comment: yes cause its the passphrase for a trust wallet account

Comment: I see, that wasn't apparent from the question's previous phrasing. I've added a mention of this and the tag to the question.

Answer (score 2):

There are only 720 (6!) possible ways to order six words, so you could write a script that generates them all and then checks whether there are any transactions associated with any.

As @meshcollider pointed out in a comment, you could then use the 4-bit checksum that mnemonic seeds include to reduce this set of possible combinations even further to about 45 seeds for which you'd need to check the addresses.